# how to send a list in form-data using dio in post method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, post, dio

[image]

I can't send list in post method using dio in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to join the list and then send to FormData like:

```
 List<int> list = [6, 12];
 var formData = json.encode({"foods": "${list.join(",")}"});
 print(formData);
```

your output will be :

> {"foods":"6,12"}